# Kitty Load Profile via URL Handler

Tags: windows, putty, mime-types

I'm able to add the Kitty SSH Handling in Firefox/IE to load the hostname via ssh://hostname.mydomain.com, however I'd like to load a session instead of a hostname, i.e. ssh://mysession. I modified the registry key for ssh/shell/open and added the -load parameter but this seems to break the functionality and does not work until it is changed back to the original:

```
kitty.exe %1
     vs
kitty.exe -load %1
```

Any idea how I can set the shell command to open with a parameter?

Comment: That gets put in the registry under HKCR.   Go search around there for kitty, you should probably be able to find it and tweak it.

Comment: That's what I did to get kitty.exe -load...but it's failing, hence the post.